# Oracle delete statement is not working in JS even if autoCommit is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, autocommit

here I want to execute 3 queries to delete record from 3 tables. Even if using auto commit true OR commit after each execute statement (currently commenting it), no changes happened in database.
First time when I used auto commit true then it worked.Now I want to delete another record but now I don't know why it's not working. Please help me in it ,I am new in node.
Note :- I am passing new parameters while deleting so params are valid.

folder.js :-

```js
const {
  dbConnection
} = require('../dbService/oracle/webfocusReporting/dbConnection');
const constants = require('../common/constant');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const getDeleteSavedFolderStatus = async (request, res) => {
  const { userID, folder } = request;
  await dbConnection.createPool();
  await dbConnection.init();
  oracledb.autoCommit = true;
  const fieldMapping = constants.FIELD_MAPPING.REPORTS;
  console.log('userId = ' + userID + '  ' + 'folder = ' + folder);
  if (userID) {
    const query1 = `DELETE FROM REPORT_PARAMS WHERE RPT_ID IN (SELECT RPT_ID FROM
                 REPORTS WHERE reports.${fieldMapping.userID} =:userID  AND reports.${fieldMapping.folder} =:folder )`;

    const query2 = `DELETE FROM WF_RPT_PARAM_JDO WHERE RPT_ID IN (SELECT RPT_ID FROM
                 REPORTS WHERE reports.${fieldMapping.userID} =:userID  AND reports.${fieldMapping.folder} =:folder )`;

    const query3 = `DELETE FROM REPORTS WHERE reports.${fieldMapping.userID} =:userID  AND reports.${fieldMapping.folder} =:folder`;

    const result1 = await dbConnection.execute(query1, [userID, folder]);
    // await dbConnection.commit();
    const result2 = await dbConnection.execute(query2, [userID, folder]);
    //await dbConnection.commit();
    const result3 = await dbConnection.execute(query3, [userID, folder]);
    //await dbConnection.commit();

    console.log('#####  Generated Query1  ###### \n' + query1);
    console.log('#####  Generated Query2  ###### \n' + query2);
    console.log('#####  Generated Query3  ###### \n' + query3);
    console.log('Result 1 =>  ' + result1.rowsAffected);
    console.log('Result 2 =>  ' + result2.rowsAffected);
    console.log('Result 3 =>  ' + result3.rowsAffected);

    let finalCount =
      result1.rowsAffected + result2.rowsAffected + result3.rowsAffected;
    await dbConnection.close();
    console.log('total count = ' + finalCount);
    return finalCount;
  }
```

my Controller file.

folderController.js :-

```js
const deleteSavedFolder = async (req, res) => {
  const sourceType = req.headers[constants.HEADERS.SOURCE_TYPE];
  const request = { sourceType, ...req.body };
  const { folder } = request;

  try {
    if (folder !== 'Default') {
      // check for default folder
      await validator.validateRenameAndDeleteSavedFolder(request, res);
      if (!res.finished) {
        const DeleteSavedFolderStatus = await folderManage.getDeleteSavedFolderStatus(
          request,
          res
        );
        if (DeleteSavedFolderStatus > 2) {
          res.send({
            [constants.FIELDS.RESPONSESTATUS]: constants.FIELDS.SUCCESS
          });
        } else {
          res.send({
            [constants.FIELDS.RESPONSESTATUS]: constants.FIELDS.FAILURE
          });
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error ===> ', error);
    erroResponse.SVC9000(res, error);
  }
};
```

Please find below logs.
Logs :-

```
Connection was successful!
==== Closing connection =======
Connection was successful!
userId = 1410intatt1^BD  folder = Test
#####  Generated Query1  ######
DELETE FROM REPORT_PARAMS WHERE RPT_ID IN (SELECT RPT_ID FROM REPORTS WHERE reports.USER_ID =:userID  AND reports.FOLDER_NAME =:folder )
#####  Generated Query2  ######
DELETE FROM WF_RPT_PARAM_JDO WHERE RPT_ID IN (SELECT RPT_ID FROM REPORTS WHERE reports.USER_ID =:userID  AND reports.FOLDER_NAME =:folder )
#####  Generated Query3  ######
DELETE FROM REPORTS WHERE reports.USER_ID =:userID  AND reports.FOLDER_NAME =:folder
Result 1 =>  0
Result 2 =>  0
Result 3 =>  0
==== Closing connection =======
total count = 0
```

Comment: *"First time when I used auto commit true then it worked"* Are you sure there are records to be deleted for the parameter values you're passing?

Comment: Yes parameters are valid. Now I want to delete another record .

Comment: Are you actually connecting to the correct DB? Also why is `dbConnection.createPool()` being called in your execution code - hopefully it doesn't recreate a new pool each time.  You should create the pool once during application initialization. And what is `dbConnection.init()`? Should you be using [`sessionCallback`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpooltagging)? Also, look at wrapping your 3 SQL statements into one PL/SQL block and using SQL%ROWCOUNT.  This would mean you only need one `connection.execute()` call which will help application performance and scalability.

Comment: I am connected to correct DB, first time it works properly then if I create same record again in table or any other record then it doesn't work. Individual 3 queries are working fine. Can you please guide me to how to merge 3 into 1 query.  Thanks for help.

Comment: When you 'create same record again' are you committing?

Comment: My issue gets solved by when I am creating record in sql Developer then I have to commit in it. Then I can delete from my API. Thanks to all.